# Unable to retrieve report data using Dynamic Action in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1

I have two tables: Application (PK: Application_ID) and App_support_domain (column: team_name, FK: Application_ID referencing Application table)

I am trying to display the data present in the Application table based on the selection of team names.

I have created a LOV popup (P2_NEW) to select the team name. [image: Popup LOV showing team names]

After selecting the team name I want to show the application data in the form of a report, so I have created a dynamic action that will show the body region which has the application data.

But the SQL query that I have written does not return any data. I think it is not taking the P3_NEW LOV value and displaying the application data.

[image: Application Design Page]
[image: Application data based on team selection]

Please let me know if you need more info/clarification.
Could you please take a look and help me out?

Comment: Did you put P2_NEW in the "Items to submit" attribute of the report ? If not, the value of P2_NEW will not be set in the session and you won't see the results based on the selected value.

Comment: Yes, I just put that and now I'm getting some 2 records irrespective of the team name I choose. It is still not taking the P2_NEW value or I may be missing something

Comment: You have P2_NEW and P3_NEW in your question. That seems unlikely - is that a typo ?

Comment: It's a typo, sorry.

Comment: Did my answer help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "show" dynamic action will not resubmit the report. Add 2 actions to the dynamic action. One to refresh and an 2nd one to show. That will force the report to to refresh. Make sure you put P2_NEW in the "Page Items to submit" for the report.